# Amazon Linux 2 AMI cannot start program with upstart

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, upstart, amazon-ami

I wanted to run my server when connection to terminal is closed but i cannot do it.

Whenever i try to `sudo start myconf_file` it returns with `start: command not found` or even `sudo initctl start myconf_file` with `initctl: command not found`.

I am trying to use upstart for Golang .exe based on this file:

```
description "start and stop the go program 'my-project'"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env USER='ubuntu'
env APP_DIR='/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/your-username/your-project-name/'
env APP_EXEC='your-project-name'

exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid ${USER} --chdir ${APP_DIR} --exec ${APP_DIR}${APP_EXEC}
```

File is placed in `/etc/init.d/`folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need for a script/startup.
Did it using `setsid`.
So `sudo setsid ./NameOfTheExe`.

Then if the process has to be killed `pidof` and `kill` can be used.

```
pidof NameOfTheExe
```

and then as id of the process shows, for example "1871"

```
sudo kill 1871
```